# I have the following gulpfile.js, which I'm executing via the command line gulp message:

Tags: sass, gulp

```
function sass() {
    return gulp
        .src("src/scss/main.scss")
        .pipe(sass({ includePaths: ["scss"] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
        .pipe(minifycss());
}
```

And i'm getting this error message:

```
C:\Users\Vipin\Desktop\starter_project>gulp sass
[15:53:51] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\starter_project\gulpfile.js
[15:53:51] Starting 'sass'...
[15:53:51] The following tasks did not complete: sass
[15:53:51] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I'm using gulp4. Please help!!!

Comment: Your code should run fine as is (although you need to `pipe(gulp.dest(<where you want your minified css>)` after the `minifycss` pipe - otherwise they aren't saved anywhere).  I suspect you are using `sass` as both the package name - in your `require` statement and as the function name.  Change one of them.

Comment: i tried doing that but it still is giving me the same error :( @Mark

Comment: In that case you should show more or all of your gulpfile.js.